# What's dangerous about echoing the SID

Tags: php, security, session, sessionid

On [**this**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) page it says

> The `htmlspecialchars()` may be used when printing the SID in order to prevent XSS related attacks.

What possible attack can someone do if you print the SID without using `htmlspecialchars()` ?

The session ID can only contain numbers and letters. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Session ID is usually **stored on the client** (eg. in the cookie or in the `GET` params), so it can be altered - by some script or even by altering the URL.

Now imagine someone that was able to **alter the cookie and change `SID` to some JS code** redirecting you to some other place. If you will print that value on your page unescaped, the user will be redirected every time unless he will clear the cookies or disable JavaScript.

In other words, **session ID is taken from the client** and is unsecure (unless you will use additional mechanism ensuring it was not altered, such as cookie signing, included in eg. some PHP frameworks), so you cannot trust it does not contain something harmful.

This is the same reason you must not use this value as safe when constructing the SQL queries (so SID is also a place where SQL injection is possible).

Comment: How would an attacker be able to change it on someone else's machine?

Comment: By putting it in the URL: `yoursite.com/?PHPSESSID=<script>alert('hi')</script>`. You can disable this by setting `session.use_trans_sid=0
session.use_only_cookies=1` in your php.ini file

Comment: @qwertymk: Cookies are the same for the same domain, so control on one of the pages (eg. by another XSS) is enough. One page is vulnerable and if you will display SID elsewhere, the other pages are also affected (one page sets SID in the cookie, other pages display it). Or if the SID from the URL (which, if then overwriting the SID in the cookie, will cause the issue to occur even when using URL without SID in it).

Comment: @John but I thought session ids can only be letters and numbers

Comment: @qwertymk: But cookies and URL parameters (as listed on the page you referred) can contain other characters also. And because they are editable by the client (also without user being aware of it), you must not treat it as secure.

Comment: @Tadeck If someone were to send someone else `yoursite.com/?PHPSESSID=<script>alert('hi')</script>` as a link, php would treat the session id on such a page as null and/or regenerate one before it starts outputting anything, so what damage is done then? Isn't that correct?

Comment: I tested it [here](http://onlinephpfunctions.com/stackoverflow/12291991/?PHPSESSID=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%22hi%22)%3C/script%3E) with [this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21dd1a7659b79ff576494ff22fdfe651710d9c59) code. As you see, when passing just numbers or letters it works, but not when you try to enter scripts.

Comment: Also with the script 'encoded' it does not work: [example](http://onlinephpfunctions.com/stackoverflow/12291991/?PHPSESSID=\x3c\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3e\x61\x6c\x65\x72\x74\x28\x22\x68\x69\x22\x29\x3b\x3c\x2f\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3e). So I think it is kind of paranoia. But since you never know, just escape it.